# Ruby Amazon book search

Tags: ruby, amazon-product-api

Does anybody have a good Ruby script for finding books (or other products) on Amazon using their API?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been using [Amazon/ECS](http://www.pluitsolutions.com/projects/amazon-ecs) with great success. One important point is that it's not GPLed (whereas Ruby/AWS seems to be), so if it's important in your case, take care.

Here is a sample:

```
require 'amazon/ecs'

# default options; will be camelized and converted 
# to REST request parameters.
Amazon::Ecs.options = {:aWS_access_key_id => [your access key]}
res = Amazon::Ecs.item_search('ruby')
```

You may also want to have a look at [some example of integration](http://github.com/thbar/mephisto_amazon/tree/master) with the Mephisto blogging system.

cheers!

Answer (score 6):

I suppose that kind of script would have to use [Ruby/AWS](http://www.caliban.org/ruby/ruby-aws/), like this [test](http://www.semanticpool.de/ruby-awss3-tests/).

You have here an [quick introduction](http://clarkware.com/cgi/blosxom/2007/02/01).

And you have there a [full example](http://www.ddj.com/showArticle.jhtml?articleID=184405959) involving searching books.

```
response = r.keyword_search
('ruby programming', 'books')
```

Answer (score 3):

VonC's third link was a partial answer.  It led me to ruby-aaws (note - different from ruby-aws).

I then found this [blog post](http://www.somelifeblog.com/2008/12/ruby-amazon-associates-web-services-aws.html) with an example of using it.

Comment: Good links. +1 to you and to your new chosen answer :)